# Create dummy variable using tidyverse?

Tags: r

How would you create a dummy variable using tidyverse? I can do it in the base R syntax by using the ifelse function, but I'm stumped by how to do it using a tidyverse function.

Comment: Please show a small reprodcuible example with expected output

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you could present your problem in detail and show the structure of your data (i.e. using dput(head(data))), others can help you in a better way.
As I understand your question, you can use `tidyverse` verbs as follow:

```
data %>% mutate(new_var = if_else(condition, 1, 0))
```